# Como poder guardar el nombre de los archivos de un array en un una base de datos

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Soy nuevo utilizando laravel y aun me faltan algunas cosas por aprender.

Estoy tratando de subir múltiples archivos y almacenarlos en una carpeta, lo cual ya funciona el problema es que me gustaría poder guardarlo en una base de datos.

En mi controlador tengo esta función:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $archivo = [];
    if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
        $imagenes = $request->file('img');

        foreach ($imagenes as $imagen) {
            $nombre_original =  time().'_'.$imagen->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension       = $imagen->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $r1              = Storage::disk('archivos')->put($nombre_original, \File::get($imagen));
            $ruta            = public_path('archivos') . "/" . $nombre_original;
        }

        Personal::create([
            'id_per' => $request['id_per'],
            'nombre' => $request['nombre'],  
            'ap' => $request['ap'], 
            'am' => $request['am'],
            'genero' => $request['genero'],
            'domicilio' => $request['domicilio'], 
            'telefono' => $request['telefono'], 
            'correo' => $request['correo'],
            'id_puesto' => $request['id_puesto'],
            'feching' => $request['feching'],
            'fecharet' => $request['fecharet'],
            'finiquito' => $request['finiquito'],
            'aguinaldo' => $request['aguinaldo'],
            'c_aginaldo' => $request['c_aginaldo'],
            'c_finiquito' => $request['c_finiquito'],
            'fecha_in' => $request['fecha_in'],
            'fecha_fin' => $request['fecha_fin'],
            'epp' => $request['epp'],
            'capacitacion' => $request['capacitacion'],
            'i_capacitacion' => $request['i_capacitacion'],
            'f_capacitacion' => $request['f_capacitacion'],
            'archivo'=> $nombre_original,
        ]);

        alert()->success('Mensaje de éxito', 'Los datos que a ingresado se han guardado correctamente.');
        return  Redirect::to('/personal');
    }
}
```

Al colocar la variable `$imagenes` para almacenar los datos del `foreach`  recibo un error como este:

> Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into personal (...)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si coloco la variable `$nombre_original` solo se almacena el ultimo dato que recorrió el array, por lo que no tengo idea de como hacer que guarde todo los nombres de los archivos subidos en el campo `archivo` de la tabla en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se puede, pero podria complicarte las cosas al momento de querer usarlos o editarlos. Tal vez sea mejor idea guardar los nombres de los archivos en otra tabla y definir una relación entre el modelo Personal y el modelo que corresponda a la tabla de archivos.

Comment: El error `Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into personal (...)` es porque la base de datos espera un `string` para esa columna, y tú le estás pasando un `array`. Debes pasarle un `string` para guardar algún dato ahí. ¿Se entiende lo que quiero decir en el primer comentario? Podrías convertir el `array` a un `string` con los nombre separados por comas, o convertir el `array` a `json`, pero guardar los nombres de archivos en otra tabla y relacionarlos con tu modelo `Personal`, creo que te facilitará las cosas a futuro.

Comment: muchas gracias realice las modificaciones que me recomendaron y funciono